# Erase-remove idiom: what happens when remove return past-the-end-iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, erase, erase-remove-idiom

I got this question when I was reading `erase-remove idiom` (item 32) from Scott Meyers ["Effective STL”](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629) book.

```
vector<int> v; 
...
v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 99), v.end());
```

`remove` basically returns the "new logical end” and elements of the original range that start at the "new logical end" of the range and continue until the real end of the range are the elements to be erased from container.

Sounds good. Now, let me ask my question:

In the above example, `remove` can return `v.end()` if 99 is not found in the `vector v`. It is basically passing `past-the-end-iterator` to erase method.

1. What happens when `past-the-end-iterator` is passed to the `erase` method?  Does standard says it a UB?
2. If it is undefined behavior, then `erase-remove idiom` example in Scott Meyer’s book should have looked like:

```
  vector<int> v; 
    ...
    vector<int>::iterator newEndIter = remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 99);
    if(newEndIter != v.end() )
    {
     v.erase(newEndIter, v.end();
    }
```

Any ideas on this?

Comment: By definition v.end() is not `past-the-end`, it is the end :x

Comment: @Matthieu M. Documentation of std::vector::end() says: "Returns an iterator referring to the past-the-end element in the vector container."

Comment: @Julien-L: That's bad wording. The end iterator is one-past-the-last element. Does the C++ spec actually say that? That'd be surprising.

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes that's the wording used here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/

Comment: @Julien-L: Not only is that site not the C++ spec, that site is notorious for misleading and even outright wrong information.  However, the [C++14 draft spec](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) (§ 23.2.1) does indeed state that "`end()` returns an iterator which is the past-the-end value for the container. "

Answer (score 10):

I would think `v.erase(v.end(), v.end())` would be well defined and erase nothing.

Comment: It is, a valid iterator is in [v.begin(), v.end()] INCLUSIVE.

Answer (score 10):

The C++ standard says that the `erase(q1,q2)` member "erases the elements in the range [q1,q2)"  (cf. section 23.1.1).  Since the range excludes the last element,

```
v.erase(v.end(), v.end());
```

is valid and erases nothing.

Comment: You may need to explain what the mathematical notation [x,y) means. Unless you have a degree in maths (or related subject) you probably don't know.

Comment: Really? I do have a degree in maths but I honestly always thought this notation was well-known.

Comment: You can find the Wikipedia page on mathematical intervals at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, until now I was convinced `[a,a)` would include `a`, but somehow the exclusion of `)` is stronger then the inclusion of `[`. Interestingly, `(a,a)` is equal to `[a,a)` and `(a,a]`.

Answer (score 2):

[C++ Reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase) claims:

> The iterator `first` does not need to be dereferenceable if `first==last`: erasing an empty range is a no-op.